# How to get Vulkan to work with AMD radeon integrated graphics?

Tags: debian, amd, radeon, vulkan

I've been at this a while and I can't seem to get Vulkan to work on my new laptop. It's this one:

https://www.dell.com/en-ca/shop/dell-laptops/new-inspiron-15-5000-laptop-amd/spd/inspiron-15-5505-laptop/ni155000_sb_s103e

`$ uname -a`:

`Linux laptop 5.9.0-0.bpo.5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.9.15-1~bpo10+1 (2020-12-31) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I've been though just about every guide there is trying to get this to work, but nothing has so far. The computer displays the desktop just fine and at the correct resolution, but it's extremely slow for anything moderately graphics intensive. I have so far followed this guide but it hasn't worked.

https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo

`$ lspci|grep VGA`:

`04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir (rev c3)`

`$ glxinfo -B`:

```
name of display: :0.0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: VMware, Inc. (0xffffffff)
    Device: llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0, 128 bits) (0xffffffff)
    Version: 18.3.6
    Accelerated: no
    Video memory: 7387MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 3.3
    Max compat profile version: 3.1
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.0
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0, 128 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.3.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 18.3.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 18.3.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```

$`vulkaninfo`:

```
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
==========
VULKANINFO
==========

Vulkan Instance Version: 1.1.97

amdgpu: Invalid PCI ID.
/build/vulkan-tools-6bmpQy/vulkan-tools-1.1.97+dfsg1/vulkaninfo/vulkaninfo.c:3845: failed with VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
```

Also here's a snipped from running steam:

```
vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices failed, unable to init and enumerate GPUs with Vulkan.
BInit - Unable to initialize Vulkan!
```

I think that the correct drivers are installed, they just aren't loaded for some reason. I really just don't know how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you have 32-bit drivers.  You shouldn't need to install any drivers for AMD graphics if the kernel is new enough, but Debian doesn't come with the firmware by default.

Comment: Also if using the kernel from backports, be sure to also use the firmwares from backports (in the non-free additional component of the repository).

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone in the future running into this issue:
I didn't really figure what exactly can be done. But reinstalling and then upgrading to debian 11 fixed the issue.